# How to automatically generate the form of piecewise function from this Floor and ceiling functions?

Tags: functions

The Floor and ceiling functions is:

```
f[x_] = Floor[x Floor[x]]
```

When the Domain of a function is [0, n), n is a positive integer

Can the segmented function form of f [x] be automatically generated when n is a positive integer?

as followings:

[image]

[image]

Comment: `PiecewiseExpand`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Floor[x Floor[x]] // PiecewiseExpand[#, 0<=x<6, Reals] &
```

Answer (score 2):

You can make specific definitions together with more general definitions. MMA will then look for the most specific definition that applies and evaluate this. E.g. in your case:

```
f[x_ /; 0 <= x < 1] = 0;
f[x_ /; 1 <= x < 2] = 1;
f[x_] := Floor[x Floor[x]]
```

Now when we plot f[x]:

Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 5}]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
pwE[n_] := Assuming[{0 <= x <= n}, PiecewiseExpand@Floor[x Floor[x]]]

pwE[5]// TeXForm
```

$\begin{cases}
 1 & 1\leq x<2 \\
 4 & 2\leq x<\frac{5}{2} \\
 5 & \frac{5}{2}\leq x<3 \\
 9 & 3\leq x<\frac{10}{3} \\
 10 & \frac{10}{3}\leq x<\frac{11}{3} \\
 11 & \frac{11}{3}\leq x<4 \\
 16 & 4\leq x<\frac{17}{4} \\
 17 & \frac{17}{4}\leq x<\frac{9}{2} \\
 18 & \frac{9}{2}\leq x<\frac{19}{4} \\
 19 & \frac{19}{4}\leq x<5 \\
 25 & x\geq 5
\end{cases}$